# How does CPU tell between MMIO(Memory Mapped IO) and normal memory access in x86 architecture

Tags: x86, intel, pci, memory-mapped-io

I've read some blogs about MMIO, they say that through MMIO, I can access IO device just as I access normal physical memory. For example, I can read some data from a device by reading a specified physical address, and the CPU will know that I'll access a device instead of real memory and it will go to read data from the device.

I'm wondering how can CPU tell whether it's a MMIO access or a normal memory access?

I guess that there is a specified physical address space that used for MMIO, but I can't find related official document. (Actually I don't even know what keywords to search for some related documents)

Comment: See my answer on [X86 Address Space Controller?](https://superuser.com/q/1226197) on superuser, basically a cross-site duplicate

Comment: @PeterCordes but how does this mapping works, I mean how does CPU knows which PCIe lane to go for a certain address, is there some specification?

Comment: Probably some bootup detection / defaults for the ROM via the southbridge, but then the firmware configured the memory controllers for what physical address the DRAM appears at, I think.  Unless that's fixed at 0 other than holes?  Presumably that info gets relayed to each individual core because its requests have to get sent over the ring bus or mesh to either a memory controller (DRAM) or the system agent (for PCIe).

Comment: The CPU (that is, the unit actually executing instructions) does not know, even if the memory controller has since been made part of the same physical die as the execution core. All the execution core knows is that the instruction stream says "read this address" or "write that address". Meanwhile, devices have been configured during boot to respond to memory accesses within specified ranges.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir: I thought the CPU core would have to know whether to send a message over the ring bus (or mesh in Xeon Scalable) to a specific memory controller vs. to the / a system agent.  Or I guess for cacheable memory accesses, probably to an L3 slice, and only if it misses then from there to a DRAM controller.  The actual pipeline only knows the memory type (configured by range of physical address), normally WB-cacheable for DRAM, and normally WC (uncacheable write-combining, weakly ordered) for device memory or UC (strongly ordered uncacheable) for MMIO.  But the OS configs that.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Is there any examples about how to configure those address ranges? And who configured those ranges? (BIOS?)

Comment: With PCI derived devices the ranges are assigned via the base address registers. And yes, my understanding is that pre-OS boot code will usually take care of this, be it BIOS or UEFI. I know osdev wiki has at least some information on this, but don't know how detailed.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir, Host Bridge IO windows are indeeded cofigured by firmware, however the OS may relocate / resize those based on other factors. What OP asks is too broad, esp. taking into account the PCIe aspect from the comment. This Q has to be closed.